# How to have Spyder auto-complete modules only available as compiled .pyc files?

Tags: python, code-completion, spyder, pyc

In contrast to pydev, spyder doesn't appear to support code completion for .pyc modules without their sources. Is there a setting I missed, or some way to fix this?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) That's not exactly true. Our mac application ships only with pyc modules for the standard library and it can code-complete most of them. Could you open an issue in our [Issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/list) and upload the pyc file that's giving you troubles?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks for your reply - strangely enough it does work now that I checked again - I meanwhile updated the pyc modules, though that shouldn't be the reason. Weird...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible.

Comment: The code completion library we are using (i.e. [rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/)) is not quite reliable but next year we are planning to move to [jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi), which seems much better in several aspects.